# I am very used to using <br> tags. Is it both the same <p></p> and double <br>?

Tags: html

I like using `<br>` in my texts. Without any `<p>`. Is there a difference and will you be laughed at if you do my practice? Is

```html
<p>Hi!</p>
<p>New paragraph</p>
```

the same as

```html
Hi!
<br>
<br>
New paragraph
```

?

Comment: visually, likely. semantically, no.

Answer (score 1):

They are very different.

`<p>` denotes a paragraph. This is a semantic meaning: by putting text inside a `<p>` tag, you are saying it is a paragraph. The browser determines how it is rendered (based on the page's style sheet and the browser's defaults), which may include spacing before or after the paragraph, or both, or neither.

`<br>` denotes a line break. It doesn't mean anything except put a line break here. It can go in any kind of block: a paragraph, a heading, a list item... anywhere.